# Double for-loop R takes a very long time

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new with R and I just made a double for-loop which takes a very long time to run. Can someone help me to change this code to make it run faster?

I have a data set with two columns: a column with the amounts paid (amount) and a column with the day the amount is paid (days). It is possible that more amounts are paid on the same day. With the code, I want to calculate the sum of all amounts paid at each day, so, for example:
day 1: $100
day 2: $150
etc.

I made the following code. As already said, it works but takes a very long time to run.

```
sum_day = rep(0,203)
 for(i in 1:7555){
   for (k in 0:203){
     if(data$days[i]==k){
     sum_day[k+1] = sum_day[k+1] + data$bedrag[i]
}}}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is it something like `sum_day <- tapply(data$bedrag, data$days, FUN=sum)`?

Comment: I suspect it's a one liner with dplyr or data.table package. Could you provide few rows of your input data and expected output ?

Comment: If your data are a data.frame this is as simple as : ```data %>% groupby("day") %>% summarise(bedrag=sum(bedrag)) %>% ungroup()``` with the ```dplyr``` package as adviced by @ManishSaraswat. Make sur to load ```dplyr``` package first with ```library(dplyr)```.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I've got the following problem. All sums which are equal to 0, disappear in the output column, while I need these one as well. How could I fix this?